# Dovecot immediately logs off user

Tags: dovecot, telnet, pop3, gmail

I'm trying to set up email on my server, and have successfully set up POP3 with gmail for my main account. When attempting to set up another user though, gmail reports `   There was a problem communicating with example.com. I can't figure out why it's working for me and not the other users. I do receive email sent to the address on the server.

One suggestion I found online was to try logging in over telnet, but strangely, it kicks me off right after I log in.

```
nona~$ telnet example.com 110
Trying 50.16.219.8...
Connected to example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
+OK Dovecot ready.
user frank    
+OK
pass password
+OK Logged in.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

thanks for any ideas and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that the user didn't have a home directory, so I think Dovecot was silently failing when it couldn't find/write to the user mailbox.

**Giving the user a home directory solved the problem.**

Comment: +1 for letting us know you solved the problem!